# using return on a DynamoDB query

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a query using AWS DynamoDB which is working fine. But I would like to return the value of my query outside the function.

```
exampleDB.query(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
  console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    var xList = (data);

    var repNum = xList.Items[0].repNum.N;
    var firstName = xList.Items[0].firstName.S;
    ...

    document.getElementById("repNum").innerHTML = repNum;
    document.getElementById("congratsName").innerHTML = " " + firstName;
    ...

    console.log(xList);
    return xList;

  }
});
```

Among other things I tried giving the function a name then calling it:

```
exampleDB.query(params, function myFunction(err, data) {
...
    }
});

console.log(myFuction());
```

But that didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a callback function to the one that calls Dynamo. Here's a tutorial on callbacks: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

For example:

```
function makeQuery(callback) {
    exampleDB.query(params, function myFunction(err, data) {
        ....
        callback(err, data);
    });
}
makeQuery(function something(err, data) {
    //this is called after the ....s are finished
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but the link is broken....can you post an example ?